# MVVM Common app.config

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, mvvm

I have MVVM application which consume an external service via WCF.

The WCF client configuration is in the app.config of the ViewModel which makes it impossible for the application to read it since the View is the start-up project so the application uses the View's configuration file.

Unless I copy the ViewModel's config file to the View config file, it couldn't load the configuration properly.

Is there any way to refer all the projects in the solution to one common configuration file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add your config file to either View or ViewModel project and refer to this config file from other projects by adding it as a [`link reference`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306234).

> Link file leaves the file in its current location and maintains a link
>   to the file from your current project.

Comment: +1 This is also very usefull when you share code with different platforms. Like I.E. WP8.1 and 8.1 etc. Or a great example, when you are making an xbap applicon and a wpf application at the same time. And yes universal I know, but haven't had the time yet =)